# Google Cloud Search: Apache Nutch connector, No IndexWriters activated - check your configuration

Tags: nutch

Refer to this thread
[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53575201/google-cloud-search-indexer-indexer-java-io-ioexception-job-failed)

I also try to use Google Cloud Search but different issue.

I stuck at "No IndexWriters activated - check your configuration"

I add conf/nutch-site.xml with example in [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53575201/google-cloud-search-indexer-indexer-java-io-ioexception-job-failed)

```
    <property>
      <name>plugin.includes</name>
      <value>protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|more|metadata)|indexer-google-cloud-search|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
      <description>Regular expression naming plugin directory names to
      include.  Any plugin not matching this expression is excluded.
      In any case you need at least include the nutch-extensionpoints plugin. By
      default Nutch includes crawling just HTML and plain text via HTTP,
      and basic indexing and search plugins. In order to use HTTPS please enable
      protocol-httpclient, but be aware of possible intermittent problems with the
      underlying commons-httpclient library.
      </description>
    </property>
```

But I did not get the output below.

```
      INFO  gcs.GoogleCloudSearchIndexWriter - Starting up!
```

Instead, I got this one.

```
    Indexer: starting at 2019-03-16 14:53:13
    Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
    Indexer: URL filtering: false
    Indexer: URL normalizing: false
    No IndexWriters activated - check your configuration

    Indexer: number of documents indexed, deleted, or skipped:
    Indexer:      1  indexed (add/update)
    Indexer: finished at 2019-03-16 14:53:14, elapsed: 00:00:01
```

Please guide me to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

You only enabled the indexer plugin (which only sends the data to the output, GCS, in this case). You still need to configure an [IndexWriter](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IndexWriters). Take a look at the [example template provided with Nutch](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/conf/index-writers.xml.template).